# Why Composer load ClassLoader in this way?

Tags: php, composer-php

Open vendor/composer/autoload_real.php and look at this code:

```php
public static function loadClassLoader($class)
{
    if ('Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' === $class) {
        require __DIR__ . '/ClassLoader.php';
    }
}
```

When:

```php
    spl_autoload_register(array('ComposerAutoloaderInitf06647a07a90b762eb34553a7bce155e', 'loadClassLoader'), true, true);
    self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
    spl_autoload_unregister(array('ComposerAutoloaderInitf06647a07a90b762eb34553a7bce155e', 'loadClassLoader'));
```

Why Composer do this? And not this:

```php
require_once __DIR__ . '/ClassLoader.php';
self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that multiple autoloaders might be present concurrently in one process if for example you run phpunit installed via composer, then your test bootstrap file will also include your project class loader, and so if we did a simple `require` it would redefine the ClassLoader class and do a fatal error. Using `require_once` would not work either since the ClassLoader.php file is present twice (one in PHPUnit, one in the project) with different paths. PHP would still include each of these once, leading in class redefinition.

This could be fixed with a simple `if (!class_exists()) {}` around the require, but unfortunately that kind of conditional class definition messes up APC on high traffic sites so we had to resort to this strange temporary autoloader hack to make it work everywhere.

Comment: Why not use `require_once` for that?

Comment: @Medvedev I updated the answer to also explain that.